# Could a temporal controller QgsDateTimeRange be a bug?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, temporal-controller

I am having an issue with getting date/time specified raster layers to animate. In trying to resolve this, I printed out the .dateTimeRangeForFrameNumber(fn) just to ensure the datetime start and end times are correct. They are correct. However, I noticed what appears to be unorthodox syntax for the QgsDateTimeRange element. It has a [ in the front and a ) in the back of the iterable. Is this to be expected or is this a possible bug? Please see screenshot of my test code with print results.

tc = self.temporal_controller.temporalController()

frame_num = tc.currentFrameNumber()

print(f'dt range = {tc.dateTimeRangeForFrameNumber(frame_num)}')

set_fixed_temporal_range(frame_num)

prints>>    dt range = <QgsDateTimeRange:[2023-10-14T11:00:00Z, 2023-10-14T12:00:00Z)>

[image]

Comment: I think that means the beginning is included in the range but the end is not. Have a look at the code to see if there are any comments

Comment: Okay, that seems reasonable. Thanks for the response.